# Create shared-library (`.so`) from static archive (`.a`) that exports only the global and visible symbols

Tags: android, c++, java-native-interface

I have a static library (`foo.a`) that contains a lot of symbols, e.g.:

```
0000000000000000 l    d  .text.finish_doctype_system_id 00000000 .text.finish_doctype_system_id
0000000000000000 gw    F .text._ZN16FlutterContainer14create_elementEPKcRKNSt6__ndk13mapINS2_12basic_stringIcNS2_11char_traitsIcEENS2_9allocatorIcEEEES9_NS2_4lessIS9_EENS7_INS2_4pairIKS9_S9_EEEEEERKNS2_10shared_ptrIN8litehtml8documentEEE        0000003c .hidden _ZN16FlutterContainer14create_elementEPKcRKNSt6__ndk13mapINS2_12basic_stringIcNS2_11char_traitsIcEENS2_9allocatorIcEEEES9_NS2_4lessIS9_EENS7_INS2_4pairIKS9_S9_EEEEEERKNS2_10shared_ptrIN8litehtml8documentEEE

...

0000000000000000 g     F .text.document_width   0000002c document_width
```

When I use `-whole-archive` to create an `.so` from that `.a`, ALL symbols appear in the `.so`. However, I only want the global and non-hidden symbols to be exported.

In the case example above, I only want `document_width` to be exported.

Comment: try adding `-x` while creating library.[man ld](https://ftp.gnu.org/old-gnu/Manuals/ld-2.9.1/html_node/ld_3.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using JNI, and are using JNI_OnLoad, you can register all your public symbols using the RegisterNatives method, and build your library using

```
-fvisibility=hidden
```

You can refer to this for more details: https://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-jni#native-libraries

Comment: That’s what I already do and this is why all but mine symbols are marked hidden.